# How to overload Bitshift Operators for a vector container?

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I use a vector STL container in order to hold a bitset, like this: `std::vector<size_t> bitset;`

I would like to overload operator<< and operator>> to perform bitshift on all bits in vector.
For example, if bitset[0] and bitset[1] hold the following (concurrently):

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011000000110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

then, `bitset = bitset >> 3;` should yield:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011000000110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: << and >> are binary operators.  overload it using the standard binary operator overloading technique...

Comment: Is it the new shifting logic you are having trouble with?

Comment: why use http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate and set the first or last value?

Comment: What's wrong with `std::bitset`?

Answer (score 0):

A `std::vector<size_t> bitset` won't be holding bits but `size_t`s. If you shift each `size_t` in the vector, you will lose bits from each `size_t`, which is not what you want, what you want is to bit shift as if the whole bit sequence is a single integer.

An `std::bitset` will give you direct indexed access to individual bits, then you can implement two free operators for left and right shift `std::bitset operator >>(std::bitset bits, uint pos)` and the `<<` version, in which you create a new bitset with the same size, and either zero the first bits until `pos` and copy the remainder from `bits` or copy from `bits` from `pos` and zero the remaining bits for right and left shifts respectively.

Not a very efficient operation BTW.

Also, unless your bitset size is static, you might want to use something like boost's `dynamic_bitset`, because the standard bitset assumes size is known at compile time.

Alternatively, you might try a `std::vector<bool>` which may actually be implemented as a bitset to act as a substitute for a dynamic bitset. But you will have to check the particular compiler implementation just to be sure it will use single bits for every boolean value.

Lastly, when you shift by 8, 16, 32 or 64 positions, it will be much more efficient to just copy the memory around using the respective width datatype instead of using bit access.